# How to put SVN Head revision number in jenkins E-mail notification?

Tags: batch-file, svn, jenkins, cmd

I am using **SVN update** command in abc.bat file and i am running this bat file as a build step in jenkins, Also i would like to mention that i have made **none** for **Source Code Management** section.
I want to include SVN Head revision in both **success** and **failure** email notification, how to fetch the SVN head revision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Source Code Management.  This provides a variable $SVN_REVISION that can be used in your Editable Email Notification.

Then execute the remaining batch instructions afterwards.

Comment: Yes i were using the same variable but now a days jenkins is creating lots of trouble and because of that it will be keep on cleaning the trunk for fresh checkout.It will be very difficult to manage if this happens frequently So decided to disable the SCM section from jenkins and using that for further steps.If you could advise how to fetch the revision number i would be very thank ful.

Comment: I was getting errors frequently like; Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host and Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\Jenkins\workspace\VE_Trunk_Nightly_Build\trunk\.svn\wc.db: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.